# 2 Forms, Same Method but different task

Tags: php, html, forms

How can I make 2 forms which has the same method? One is responsible to open editaddresss.php with hidden addresse ID, and the second form (editaddress.php)should trigger controller and repository to save the data?

The problem is, as soon as I click "Edit Address" button on profile.php, triggers editAddress() method in controller. But I want to only happen when is clicked on editaddress.php

Profile.php

```
<form action="editaddress.php" method="POST" id="form1">
   <tr>
      <input type="hidden" name="addressid" value="<?php echo $perssonalAddress->getAddressid(); ?>">
               <td><?php echo $perssonalAddress->getStreet(); ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $perssonalAddress->getZip(); ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $perssonalAddress->getCity(); ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $perssonalAddress->getCountry(); ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $perssonalAddress->getType(); ?></td>
               <td><input type="submit" id="removeitem" value="Edit Address" form="form1"></td>
 </form>
```

Editaddress.php

```
<form action="editaddress" method="POST" name="editadresse" id="form2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="update">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $getPersonalAddress->getAddressid(); ?>" name="addressid">
                    <label for="street">Street</label>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $getPersonalAddress->getStreet() ?>" id="street" name="street">
                    <label for="zip">ZIP</label>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $getPersonalAddress->getZip() ?>" id="zip" name="zip">
                    <label for="city">City</label>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $getPersonalAddress->getCity() ?>" id="city" name="city">
                    <label for="country">Country</label>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $getPersonalAddress->getCountry() ?>" id="country" name="country">
                    <input type="submit" class="login" id="login" value="Update Address" name="editadresse" form="form2">
                </form>
```

Controller

```
    /**
     * Get Customers specific Address
     */
    public function editAddress(): void
    {
        //Error and Success Messages
        $error = false;
        $success = false;

        //Error if there is no such an address
        $message = false;


        //Get the specific customer address
        $getPersonalAddress = $this->profileService->getAddressById();

        if ($getPersonalAddress === false) {
            $message = $this->profileService->getMessages();
        }

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $this->addressForm->isValid($_POST)) {
            $this->profileService->updateCustomerAddress();
            $success = $this->profileService->getMessages();
        }else {
            $error = $this->addressForm->getFormErrorMessage();
        }

        //Render to View
        $this->render('editaddress', ['getPersonalAddress' => $getPersonalAddress, 'message' => $message, 'error' => $error, 'success' => $success]);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a specific framework here? I expect you need two action methods - one for returning the specific address based on the ID, and one to save the edited data. You seem to have only shown the latter. It's unclear what action you're expecting the first form to trigger.

Comment: No I don't. Like I said, first form is responsible to save the address id as hidden input value, and with that I am able to edit one specific address by ID. I could have used a href, but than the link is editable.

Comment: The form is editable too, if someone knows what to do. That's not the point I'm making. With a link you'd have a similar issue - you seem to be trying to get one PHP action method to do two different tasks...that's not how MVC works.

Comment: Why not just use two different methods/controllers for two different forms? Also, `action="editaddress"` is probably missing the `.php`. `form="form2"` is not needed when the element is inside the form. `<input>` and `<form>` are not allowed inside `<tr>`

Comment: The thing is that I used two different methods. But the thing is that if user types something wrong or leaves field empty, I can't display error messages on editaddress.php anymore.

Comment: Why not? It's unclear why that would be difficult, if you've designed the structure properly. Try fixing that problem instead of looking for unconventional workarounds. Show us a [mre] of that issue if you need help with it.

Comment: I'll figure it out. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching this incorrectly. You are trying to get one end-point (editaddress.php) to do two different things.

instead, you should have one end-point for generating a form with the details filled in.

and a different end-point for recording data saved from that form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I did that. But since I use specific validation, I want to display messages on editaddress.php if the forms are incorrect. But If I use another method (which works perfectly), for instance editCustomerAddress() and use that as form method, then I can't display messages anymore.